# Accessing specific file structure firebase storage

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have a specific folder structure in firebase storage that looks something like:
`'gs://example.appspot.com/folderA/folderB/documentName'`.

I am using a document viewer on my website that takes a URL. My question is, how do I reference the above location as a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the JS Client SDK, one solution is to call the `getDownloadURL()` method on the Cloud Storage reference. Something along the following lines:

```
import { getStorage, ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const storage = getStorage();
getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'folderA/folderB/documentName'))
  .then((url) => {
     console.log(url)
  });
```

Comment: Hi @Charmalade, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. THanks for your reply - you definitely helped me get the the right path:

Comment: await  firebase.storage().ref().child(link).getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
        return url
    });